# Error when setup require.js config

Tags: javascript, requirejs, ractivejs

Main.js

```
require.config({
paths: {
    ractive: "../lib/ractive",
    rv: "../loaders/rv",
    waitSeconds: 200
},

name: "main",
out: "../dist/js/main.js",
stubModules: ["rv"]});
```

Feed.js

```
require(["../lib/ractive", "../loaders/rv!../templates/Feed/Main"],
function (ractive, feedTemplate) {
 console.log(ractive);
 console.log(feedTemplate);
    "use strict";
```

Index.html

```
<script src="js/require.js" data-main="js/modules/Main" ></script>
<script src="js/modules/Feed.js"></script>
```

Ractive loads fine, but the rv doesn't load well.

Error message for rv. `Load timeout for modules: ../loaders/rv!../templates/Feed/Main_unnormalized2,ractive`

Is there something I've forgotten?

Answer (score 0):

`rv` is a [RequireJS plugin](http://requirejs.org/docs/plugins.html). Since you already mapped `rv` to its path in the `paths` config, all you need to do is simply prefix its name followed by a `!`.

```
require(["../lib/ractive", "rv!../templates/Feed/Main"], ...);
```